# iPhone - InApp purchase Restore products prompt signin alert twice

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, restore

I am providing Restore Functionality for Non-Consumable Products.
When I click on to Restore it prompts the SignIn alert, 
I use the Existing Apple Id for SignIn, after entering UserId and Password and taps on Ok then SignIn Alert Prompted once again.

Why it's prompted again once I entered user details?

[image: Sign In Alert]

**EDIT:
Restore Process Code:**

```
-(void)RestorePurchasedItems
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"=======%@",transactions);
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {

    }
}
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSMutableArray* purchasableObjects  = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];   
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasableObjects addObject:productID];
    }
    self.OnSuccessRestored(purchasableObjects); //Block Call to access the products
}
```

Comment: Need more information, can you provide code...

Comment: I am testing Restore functionality in SandBox Environment using TestUser Id and this issue comes in picture

Comment: On restore button click i am calling this method:
-(void)RestorePurchasedItems
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

Comment: Just fire [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; Try it.

Comment: I used Only [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; but still its repeated :(

Comment: Hi [Sudhakar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/880443/sudhakar) i have editted my question with all code... please, check if you have any idea.

Comment: @RayofHope Have you find the solution for it?

Comment: @bhavin do you have the same issue?

Comment: @luca yes I do have the same issue, I had followed RayofHope's suggestion and it was gone.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't Know what happened with iTunes connect issue gone away magically :) :)

Comment: I'm still having the same problem with the exact same situation (restore non-consumable IAP, got iTunes login twice)

Comment: @thomers I am testing the same situations in IOS simulator and facing the same issue. so, do I have to make any code changes to handle it? OR is it natural way?

Comment: @bhavin No code changes necessary for me - it's a temporary Apple glitch that I chose to ignore, and it went away after some time (showing login alert only once).