# what does iphone exactly do after restoreCompletedTransactions is called

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

which kind of Transactions will be restore after this method? and what if User's account did not match with one of the transaction?
i ask this question because when i am developing with IAP, and use several account to buy the product,and after i call this method, apple display some popups to let me login ,and the mail of the accounts are really mess。

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at Ray Wenderlich's tutorials on in-app purchases. In particular, [Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). Towards the end of this tutorial in the section titled "Restoring Transactions", it states:

> What that [restoreCompletedTransactions] will do is contact iTunes Connect and find out which non-consumable products the user has already purchased. It will then call paymentQueue:updatedTransactions for each of these, with the SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored case.

Comment: i've use several accounts and bought several times of a product, after i call restoreCompletedTransaction. apple alterts several popups with different mail addresses. ""find out which non-consumable products the user has already purchased""you said,so how does apple distinguish the "user".

Comment: The email address in the alert is the iTunes account you are logged into on your device. Once you've entered your password, the payment queue sends a request to the App Store to restore the transactions for that user account. Apple distinguishes the user based on the iTunes account details you enter in the alert prompt. I have not heard of multiple alerts popping up for one call to restore. The only question related to this I could find on SO was [this issue with iTunes Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378543/iphone-inapp-purchase-restore-products-prompt-signin-alert-twice).